# footer at the middle?

Tags: html, css, footer

I've been tracing my codes but to no avail. the footer on my About Me page is always placed at the middle, covering the contents. what should I do?

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
min-height:100%;
position:relative;
   }


#footer {
width:1010px;
height:80px;
position:absolute;
bottom:50px;
left:0 auto;
background: rgb(54, 25, 25); 
    background: rgba(54, 25, 25, .5);
  }
```

Comment: <div id="wrapper">
  
  <div id="footer"><p id="text"><center><font color="#F9E2A6" size="3" face="Open Sans">&copy; 2013 by Jake Buela |<b> /*footer message*/ </b>| /*footer message*/ <br> /*footer message*/></font></center> </p>
</div></div>

Comment: Make an edit, don't put code into comments.  Also, what's the rest of your css? IF you don't have `html, body {height: 100%;}`, then the wrapper will **not** extend the full height of the browser.  Finally, if the footer is position: absolute, there's nothing preventing it from covering the contents above it unless you provide some padding in your #wrapper element to allow for the space the footer takes.

Answer (score 0):

just add some min-height to `div` just below `body` and close the `div` just before footer div ie

```
<body>
<div style="overflow:auto;padding-bottom:100px;min-height:670px;">

 <!-- all html codes -->
</div>

<!-- now the footer div -->
<div class="footer>
#footer htmls
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

i found a great solution on this website that has been working on my page:

[check it out](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/)

it .footer and .push classes, the push is what keeps the footer "stuck" to the bottom of the page...